# How does picasso know it runs in a list?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-imageview, picasso

I was looking the doc for [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) and it mentions:

```
Features
ADAPTER DOWNLOADS
Adapter re-use is automatically detected and the previous download canceled.

@Override public void getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  SquaredImageView view = (SquaredImageView) convertView;
  if (view == null) {
    view = new SquaredImageView(context);
  }
  String url = getItem(position);

  Picasso.get().load(url).into(view);
}
```

but from that example they provided I don't understand how Picasso understand that it is loading an image in an adapter or that the previous download can be cancelled.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't.  It keeps track of all the images its currently downloading, and if the same URI is requested again it will not start a new download request (it says the old one will be canceled, more accurately the old download will continue, but the callbacks on the old download won't happen and will be replaced by the new one).  So it doesn't know it's in a list, but this behavior is what a list would want.

It also knows what view its being downloaded into, so it probably uses that as well.  If the same view is being loaded into multiple times, only the last one will actually be honored.

Comment: If the URI is the same, it means the same image? But in a list we have multiple different images.

Comment: Yes, the same URI means the same image.  In the list you'll have different images, but each different image will have its own URI.

Comment: So what the documentation says is that if a list has multiple same images the old callbacks are not called which means that we have scrolled away from the previous requests? Is that right?